# Export Token Holders list of a token to csv

Tags: etherscan, export

I'm trying to do some distribution calculations on a couple of tokens and could use an export of the token holders list that I can find in Etherscan when I search for a specific token. Since Etherscan is showing the list I was hoping the API would have a function for this, but it looks to me like it doesn't. Please bear with me as I am totally new to this and am not able to really build anything. I know how to fiddle with some APIs and that's about it.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a standalone tool which does the same.

- Take a token contract address
- Iterate over all `Transfer` events for token using `eth_getLogs` JSON-RPC API
- Build a local database of these events
- Allow you to use SQL to query any account balance on any point of time (block num)

[You can find the command line application execution example how to build the token holder database here](https://docs.tokenmarket.net/erc-20-holders.html)

[The core Python logic is here](https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/sto/blob/master/sto/ethereum/scanner.py).

You can also trivially export this list from SQLite database to CSV file.

There are some quirks here and there: for example detecting mint / creation event for some tokens is not straightforward. Thus, you will may negative balance on the account receiving initial total supply if you rely on `Transfer` event only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [https://etherscan.io/exportData?type=tokens&contract=0xa02e3bb9cebc03952601b3724b4940e0845bebcf

Replace *Contract* with your token contract address

Comment: Can we export all token holders addresses into a smart contract?

Comment: @FarihaAbbasi you need to insert them into the smart contract. Costing loads of gas